# symfony dynamically add translation based on condition

Tags: symfony, translation

I'm searching for a way to add a translation to an existing translation catalogue during runtime.

I have a working symfony 2.3 application which uses translations in de/en/fr/it and fetches all available translation keys from /Resources/translations/messages..yml.

Now if a user logs in I want to have the possibility to override some of the already loaded labels based on setting for that user (e.g. textfield in DB which holds key-value-pairs).

E.g.

```
messages.en.yml
  company.name.short: Company profile

Usersetting:
  company.name.short: Profile for company
```

I found no way to add/override keys to the existing catalogue or to make them available in twig. Is there a Bundle or a setting or some Symfony magic to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to extend Symfony's own translation class for this. This article explains how to do that:

http://www.webtipblog.com/extend-symfony-2-translator-to-log-untranslated-messages-to-a-database/

The key point is to override the "translator.class" parameter in your config, and then point it to your own class that first checks for database overrules and will defer to the symfony default implementation if it cannot find one.

Comment: Thanks a ton, this puts me in the right direction. I simply inject the user based translations into my own translator class and return them if necessary using the trans-function...